# Cache Response That Uses Include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, include

I've learned how to use the Rails.cache.fetch function to cache database calls, however, when I respond to the request, I include the contents of several related tables, for example

```
tracks = Rails.cache.fetch("events-by-track", :expires_in => 12.hours) do
  Track.find(:all)
end
respond_with(tracks, :include => {:events => {:include => :speaker}})
```

This caches (I think) the call Track.find(:all), but is it also caching the included events and speaker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not caching those.  You'll have to put those inside the call to include them as well.  For example, something like this:

```
tracks = Rails.cache.fetch("events-by-track", :expires_in => 12.hours) do
  Track.find(:all, :include => {:events => :speaker})
end
respond_with(tracks)
```

Example of array of associated objects:

```
tracks, events = Rails.cache.fetch("events-by-track", :expires_in => 12.hours) do
  tracks = Track.find(:all, :include => [:events])
  events = tracks.collect(&:events)
  tracks, events
end
respond_with(tracks)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this gives me an error. Association named 'include' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: If I just make it just Track.find(:all, :include => [:events]) it returns all the tracks, but doesn't include the events.

Comment: I've updated my solution.  The mechanics aren't as important as the concept that what goes in the Rails.cache.fetch block is what is actually cached.  Remember that how you have implemented your caching might not allow you to store these associations properly.  You might need to modify what you are actually storing as well. For example, you might need to return an array of associated objects.

Comment: Another more productive solution might be to cache your views instead of the actual ActiveRecord objects.  That way you can cache what is actually displayed after this query is used.